# Triggering CI builds using Jenkins on remote build machine

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to implement CICD with Jenkins. I have my code in git repo. The moment I make a change to git repo files, I wish to trigger a Build that should run on remote machine. 
This means If I change a file in Git Repo 10 times, I should have 10 Builds, each build corresponding to one change.
Can anyone tell me how this can be done ?
I tried to make use of post-commit hook, but its not working.

Comment: What is not working? Show what you tried

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of GIT? Do you use?  If you share you config details of webhook and Jenkins additional info can be provided. Per my experience it is a two step process.

1. Enable the webhook in GIT
2. Create a job with appropriate configuration to map to the repository and get triggered on commit